# Can we provide branch level access to the files i.e to even view the files in the codecommit portal

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I have a use case where I need to restrict the user's access to views and access the files in other branches apart from the branch assigned to that specific user.

In codecommit, I'm trying to achieve this using the below policy.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                ...
                "codecommit:Blob",
                "codecommit:GetTree"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:ap-south-1:581828246145:access-permissions-demo-repo",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "codecommit:References": [
                        "refs/heads/some-branch"
                    ]
                },
                "Null": {
                    "codecommit:References": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy is restricting access to all the branches. Not sure what I'm missing here. Very much appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this.

Comment: I don't know anything about what aws-codecommit's interface does, but Git itself literally cannot do this because branch names are meaningless; only the *commit graph* matters, and if a commit graph fragment makes a commit reachable, someone with a clone of the repository can get that commit. Besides that, in modern Git, you can retrieve any commit directly by its hash ID if you know the hash ID.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do with

```
"Effect": "Deny"
```

Check this out:
[Limit pushes and merges to branches in AWS CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-conditional-branch.html)